# model and view in gtk

Tags: linux, gtk

hi every one i want to ask does it make any difference that we make model first or view first 
in gtk tutorials if cant under stand that in some tutorials

gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

is called  after

gtk_list_store_new(N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING);

while in other place it is vise the versa

i am tolally confused kindly help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't matter. The `G_TYPE_STRING` column indicates the types of columns in the *model*; the `GtkCellRendererText` indicates the types of columns in the *view*. These can be different columns, a column in the model might not be displayed in the view at all, or two columns in the model can be displayed in one column in the view, or maybe some more complicated relationship.